# Application not installed error in android 4.0

Tags: android

I am using google maps in my application. so i required the below shared library in manifest file.

*android:name="com.google.android.maps"*           and the application is working fine.

The same is not working in android 4.0 due to unavailabilty of shared library google maps.

If i remove the above library in manifest file ,it is working in 4.0 device too.

So My question is how to make it work on 4.0 as well as in other devices.

Please help me.  Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare different APK file for ICS. Google Play supports installing multiple APKs for different versions

Comment: is there any way to support with one apk file

Comment: NO I don't think so.  Such multi-platform targetting are allowed with other resource files, but for Manifext, NO. A manifest is an identifier of characteristics of an APK distribution.  You cannot have multiple identities to a single object, that's why you cannot do this.